# Zend-Framework. (composer development-enable)

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, development-mode

Good day everyone.

In the new version of Zend Framework when I enable Development mode

***$* composer development-enable**

application works good. When I disable Development mode

***$* composer development-disable**

it stops working

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Route with name "album" not found'.......**

In tutorial written "*Never enable development mode in production*".
I can not understand, if after completion I will send site to the server how it will run on the server if it does not work on my local-server. With former release Zend framework 2 such questions were not. I'm just learning and ask to give detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "cahed" files:

```
rm /data/cache/module-classmap-cache.application.module.cache.php
rm /data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php
```

or

```
cd /data/cache/
rm *
```

In develop mode, files are automatically refreshed. In production they need to delete manually.

Comment: Thank you very much